# Clean links in: the_author_meta('description')

Tags: author, links, description, customization

I need to clean any links returned from the_author_meta('description')

The code I use is simply that:

```
<p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
```

I Searched old question but could not find the right anwer.. ideas anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    // grab description,
    // note the "get_", we're not echoing the author meta, we're returning it
    $user_description = get_the_author_meta('description');
    // removing all HTML tags:
    echo strip_tags($user_description);
    // removing all tags apart from paragraphs:
    echo strip_tags($user_description,'<p>');
    // removing just anchors (i.e. <a> tags):
    echo preg_replace(array('{<a[^>]*>}','{</a>}'),array('',''),$user_description);
    // removing all links including their text (i.e. <a href="...">...</a>):
    echo preg_replace('{<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>}','',$user_description);
?>
```

Reference:

- [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)
- [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: I also tried strip_tags but it didnt work.. However preg_replace works like a charm :) thanks a lot man